# How to prove intersection between languages L1 (belongs to NP) and L2 (belongs to P) actually belongs to NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, np

I have to prove that if L <=p L1 intersection L2, where L1 and L2 are described as above, L belongs to NP.

I thought about the definitions of P and NP and built a DTM D that decides L2 and a NTM N that decides L1. Then I tried to build a NTM NN that accepts when both D and N accept on some input w.

Now,did I really prove that intersection between L1 and L2 is in NP by constructing NTM NN? Thx in advance

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: Idea is correct, however you have to explicitly create a single turing machine to do the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove something more, intersection of two NP languages is also in NP.

Suppose you have polynomial time non-deterministic turing machines $M_1$ for $L_1$ and $M_2$ for $L_2$. We can modify $M_1$ as follows: Whenever any non-deterministic thread of $M_1$ accepts input string, say $w$, we run $M_2$ on $w$, if $M_2$ then accepts $w$, accept the input, otherwise reject.

The resulting machine is polynomial time non-deterministic.